# images.xcassets isnt created when I create a new project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image

On xcode 4.6.3, creating an ios single view application, after it is created and saved the images.xcassets folder isnt anywhere to be found, preventing me from uploading any images (according to the tutorial I am following, moving images to images.xcassets is the next step)

Do I have to download it or import it from somewhere else?!

[isnt it supposed to be in the left area?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyGLB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

images.xcassets is xCode 5 feature

Answer (score 1):

this feature is only available in XCode 5. You can move images into anywhere in the project and they will be avilable in your code. It does not have to be inside images.xcassets. Just drag the image files and drop it inside the files browser area of the XCode 4.